# getting first character of string : SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, arrays

I am learning python using `codeacademy` tutorial

there is this instruction:

> Set new_word equal to the slice from the 1st index all the way to the
>   end of new_word. Use [1:len(new_word)] to do this.

my code:

```
s = "Charlie"
new_word = [0:len(s)]
```

error:

```
  File "python", line 3
    new_word = [0:len(s)]
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know it is embarrassing but please help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That syntax must be used *with* the string variable:

```
new_word = s[0:len(s)]
```

The part in the brackets is like saying "grab this part", but you need `s` outside to tell it what to grab a part from.

Also, notice that since you used 0 instead of 1, your result will be the same string as the original --- that is, your code won't really accomplish anything.  In fact, what codeacademy is telling you do is more easily done with just `s[1:]`, but perhaps it will talk about that later.

Comment: you right that fixed it, aren't python array zero based, how is `1` going to work

Comment: @AlPacino: Right, they are zero based, so going from zero to `len(s)` means to go from the beginning to the end --- in other words, the whole thing.  Look at the codeacademy quote you pasted in your question.  It shows `[1:len(new_word)]`, not `[0:len(new_word)]`.

Comment: fair, thank you for taking the time to explain